# Why is this CSS selector returning no results?

Tags: css, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am following along with a webscraping example in Automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python but my CSS selector is returning no results

```
import bs4
import requests
import sys
import webbrowser

print("Googling ...")
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
linkelems = soup.find_all(".r a")

numopen = min(5, len(linkelems))
for i in range(numopen):
webbrowser.open('https://google.com' + linkelems[i].get('href'))
```

Has google since modified how they store search links ?
From inspecting the search page elements I see no reason this selector would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1.) Instead of `soup.find_all(".r a")` use `soup.select(".r a")` Only `.select()` method accepts CSS selectors

2.) Google page needs that you specify `User-Agent` header to return correct page.

```
import bs4
import sys
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

print("Googling ...")
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]), headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
linkelems = soup.select(".r a")

for a in linkelems:
    print(a.text)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Googling ...
Tree - Wikipediaen.wikipedia.org › wiki › Tree

... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

A complimentary answer to [Andrej Kesely's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62130242/15164646) answer.

If you don't want to deal with figuring out what selectors to use or how to bypass blocks from Google, then you can try to use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that bypass blocks, data extraction, and more is already done for the end-user. All that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Example code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = { 
    "engine": "google",              # search engine
    "q": "fus ro dah",               # query
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), # environment variable with your API-KEY
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  link = result['link']
  print(link)

------------
'''
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unrelenting_Force_(Skyrim)
https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fus-ro-dah
https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unrelenting_Force
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fus%20ro%20dah
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/4889/
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/14094/
https://tenor.com/search/fus-ro-dah-gifs
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.